# python list add multiple varaiable, but print always the last one, is variable overwrite?

Tags: python-3.x

string

Date,Open

2020-04-08,387.799988

2020-04-09,390.000000

my code

```
    headers = self.str.split("\n")[0]
    results = self.str.split("\n")[1:]
    header_list = headers.split(",")
    dict_share = []
    dict_head = {}
    for i, value in enumerate(header_list):
        dict_head[i] = value
    price_list = {}
    for price in results:
        price_str = price.split(",")
        # print(price_str)
        if 'null' not in price_str:
            for i, temp in enumerate(price_str):
                price_list[dict_head[i]] = temp
            print(price_list)
            dict_share.append(price_list)
            print(dict_share)
```

output

```
{'Date': '2020-04-08', 'Open': '387.799988'}
[{'Date': '2020-04-08', 'Open': '387.799988'}]
{'Date': '2020-04-09', 'Open': '390.000000'}
[{'Date': '2020-04-09', 'Open': '390.000000'}, {'Date': '2020-04-09', 'Open': '390.000000'}]
```

I found all the dict of dict_share are always the last price_list list, the previous price_list was overwrite by the last one? how to avoid this?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem myself, this is about deepcopy.your new vlaue must store in a new address,so you need copy.deepcopy()

```
for price in results:
price_str = price.split(",")
if 'null' not in price_str:
    for i, temp in enumerate(price_str):
        price_list[dict_head[i]] = temp
    print(price_list)
    new_price = copy.deepcopy(price_list)
    dict_share.append(new_price)
    print(dict_share)
```